# Pyspark datafrome: How to remove too many 000 after decimal number

Tags: python, database, dataframe, pyspark, databricks

I have an existing dataframe, named df1, there is one column with numbers, there are too many 00000 after decimal, How to remove the unnecessary 0 and keep only 4 digit after point?

df1

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A | 13.89450000 |
| B | 11.56300000 |
| C | 25.45000000 |

I want to achieve the following

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A | 13.8945 |
| B | 11.5630 |
| C | 25.4500 |

Comment: you could round it to desired decimal points

Comment: @Emma, which databricks are you using? azure,aws or community?

Answer (score 0):

To preserve the ending zeros with the specific length, you could use the format_number function.

```
df1.withColumn('Value', f.format_number('Value', '#####.####')) \
  .show()
```

Then, the number will be formatted with 5 integer digits and 4 decimals.